# Why does the scattering wave vector and reciprocal lattice vector have to be the same?

Tags: crystals, scattering-cross-section, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

In Introduction to Solid state physics 8th edition by Charles Kittel. The scattering amplitude is defined as, $$F=\int dV n_G exp[i(\bf{G-\Delta k}).\bf{r}]$$ where **G** is the reciprocal lattice vector and $\Delta k$ is the scattering vector. It goes on to state that when $\Delta k \neq G $ the integral goes to zero. Can someone help with the proof for the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the distributional identity
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k x} \, dx = 2 \pi \delta(k).
$$
In particular, this implies that
$$
\iiint e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} \, dV = \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k_x x} \, dx \right] \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k_y y} \, dy \right] \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k_z z} \, dz \right] \\= (2 \pi)^3 \delta(k_x) \delta(k_y) \delta(k_z) = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}).
$$
This distribution vanishes for all $\vec{k} \neq 0$.

As to why this identity is valid, there's [a fairly good discussion over at Mathematics StackExchange.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343859/why-does-integrating-a-complex-exponential-give-the-delta-function)  At a "physics" level of rigor, it is probably best seen as a logical consequence of the properties of the Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform.